# How can we guess one solution of the equation $y''+\frac{2}{x}y'+y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the equation $$\frac{1}{x^2} \, \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=-y.$$ I converted it to this equation $y''+\frac{2}{x}y'+y=0$. How can we guess one solution of the equation $y''+\frac{2}{x}y'+y=0$? Is there any way to solve it generally?

Comment: Try power series

Comment: Try the change of function $z=\dfrac{y}{x}$. In general the equation $y''+\dfrac nxy'+y=0$ has solutions involving Bessel functions of the first kind if $n$ is odd, and trigonometric functions if $n$ is even. To guess the form of the solution, the power series method is nice.

Comment: @user170231 Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I got it. You've got a point there. Appreciate that.

Comment: For guessing, you may observe that if the first-order term was absent, the solution would be a linear combinatiuon of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. The you could try an ansatz like $y(x)=g(x) sin(x)$ and see what conditions you get for $g(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An efficient method, based on guessing and practice, is to let $ y = f(x)/x $ which leads to
$$ y^{'} = \frac{x \, f^{'} - f}{x^2} \hspace{5mm} \text{and} \hspace{5mm}  y^{''} = \frac{x^2 f^{''} - 2 f^{'} + 2 f}{x^3} $$
and brings the differential equation
$$ x \, y^{''} + 2 \, y^{'} + x \, y = 0$$
into the form
$$ f^{''} + f = 0. $$
Solving this equation gives $ f(x) = A \, \cos(x) + B \, \sin(x) $ and
$$ y(x) = \frac{A \, \cos(x) + B \, \sin(x)}{x}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Assume a solution with power series and derivatives

$$y(x) = \sum_{n\ge0} a_n x^n \implies y'(x) = \sum_{n\ge0} (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n \implies y''(x) = \sum_{n\ge0} (n+1) (n+2) a_{n+2} x^n$$

Putting these into the ODE yields

$$\begin{align*}
0 &= y'' + \frac2x y' + y \\[1ex]
&= xy'' + 2y' + xy \\[1ex]
&= \sum_{n\ge0} (n+1)(n+2) a_{n+2} x^{n+1} + 2 \sum_{n\ge0} (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n + \sum_{n\ge0} a_n x^{n+1} \\[1ex]
&= \sum_{n\ge1} n(n+1) a_{n+1} x^n + 2 \sum_{n\ge0} (n+1)a_{n+1} x^n + \sum_{n\ge1} a_{n-1}x^n \\[1ex]
&= 2a_1 + \sum_{n\ge1} \bigg((n+2)(n+1) a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}\bigg) x^n \\[1ex]
\end{align*}$$

Let $a_0=A$. The coefficients are governed by the recurrence

$$\begin{cases}a_0 = A \\ 2a_1 = 0 \\ (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+1} + a_{n-1} = 0 & n\ge1\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}a_0 = A \\ a_1 = 0 \\ a_n = -\frac{a_{n-2}}{n(n+1)} & n\ge2\end{cases}$$

and we have for $k\in\Bbb N$,

$$\begin{cases} a_{2k-1} = 0 \\ a_{2k} = \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} A\end{cases}$$

so that a fundamental solution to the ODE is

$$y_1(x) = \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} x^{2k} = \boxed{\frac{\sin(x)}x}$$

---

Reduce the order to find another solution. Let $y_2(x)=z(x)y_1(x)$. Substitute into the ODE and solve the subsequent linear equation.

$$\begin{align*}
0 &= x \left(z'' y_1 + 2z'{y_1}' + z{y_1}''\right) + 2 \left(z' y_1 + z {y_1}'\right) + x z y_1 \\[1ex]
&= z'' \sin(x) + 2z' \cos(x)\\[1ex]
&= w' \sin(x) + 2w \cos(x) & w(x) = z'(x) \\[1ex]
&= w' \sin^2(x) + w \sin(2x) \\[1ex]
&= \left(w \sin^2(x)\right)' \\[2ex]
\implies w(x) &= C_1 \csc^2(x) \\[2ex]
\implies z(x) &= C_1 \cot(x) + C_2
\end{align*}$$

Then the other fundamental solution is

$$y_2(x) = \cot(x) \cdot \frac{\sin(x)}x = \boxed{\frac{\cos(x)}x}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$y''+\frac{2}{x}y'+y=0$$
$$xy''+2y'+xy=0$$
$$xy''+y'+y'+xy=0$$
$$(xy')'+y'+xy=0$$
$$(xy'+y)'+xy=0$$
$$(xy)''+xy=0$$
This is a linear second order DE with constant coefficients that you can easily integrate.
$$r^2+1=0 \implies r=\pm i$$
$$xy(x)=C_1\cos x +C_2 \sin x$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=\dfrac 1 x (C_1\cos x +C_2 \sin x)}$$

Comment: veryyyy good ! <3

Comment: You're welcome and thanks @Yaser